# excel file reading one column and that rows continiously

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel file with two columns. I want to get one column and all its rows then 2nd column and all that rows. In the same way I should have those columns repeatedly of 12 columns.

[image]

I have used below code but I am not getting required output where I am getting `Emp_name` in first column but I should get it in second column.

```
for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
{

    if (Cnum == 1)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add((ShtRange.Cells[1, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString());
        for (int Rnum = 1; Rnum <= 9; Rnum++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add((ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString());

        }
    }
    else if (Cnum == 2)
    {

        dt.Columns.Add((ShtRange.Cells[1, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString());


        for (int Rnum = 1; Rnum <= 9; Rnum++)
        {

            dt.Rows.Add((ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, 2] as Excel.Range).Value2).ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: OK, and... does this code go wrong somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I dont think there is any problem in your code...Here is a simple method that get's your excel content in `dataset`

```
            ds = new DataSet();
            string myConnStr = "";
            if (txtdestination.Contains(".xlsx"))
            {
                myConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtdestination.ToString() + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
            }
            else
            {

                myConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + txtdestination.ToString() + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
            }
            OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(myConnStr);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", myConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            myConn.Open();
            adapter.Fill(ds);


            myConn.Close();
```

**Note** you need to have sheetname as `Sheet1`

`txtdestination` is the path of your excel file